# gstreamer-imx video streaming and encoding

Tags: gstreamer-1.0, imx6

I am currently using an Nitrogen 6 Max development board. I am attempting to retrieve video from my webcam through v4l2src so that the feed back be streamed and encoded to be saved.

This is the pipeline, and it works:

```
  v4l2src device="/dev/video2" ! tee name=t
      t. ! queue ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
      t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Then I attempted to use the imx-gstreamer library. I spent time looking around and found that this works:

```
   gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc num-buffers=1000 ! \
       video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! \
       h264parse !  avdec_h264 ! filesink location=cx1.mp4
```

However, when I attempt to use "tee" to split up the video source, it just freezes and my terminal session locks up.

```
   gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc num-buffers=1000 ! autovideoconvert ! tee name=t \
       t. ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! filesink location=cx1.mp4 \
       t. ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! autovideosink
```

I tried isolating the issue by encoding through tee, and realize that this it runs, but the video file that it generates is corrupted:

```
   gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc num-buffers=1000 ! tee name=t \
       t. ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! \
       h264parse !  avdec_h264 ! filesink location=cx1.mp4
```

I tried using queues, videoconvert, but it does not seem to work.

Also, another question here. I am new to GstElement capabilities, which is what decides which element can be linked (i.e, a *v4l2src* video/x-raw capability includes I420, that's why I can link this element to *imxvpuenc_h264*). However, for the element tee, does it split and replicate the capability of the src?

I am new to gstreamer, and I can't seem to work around this issue. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

A few hints to help you out:

- As a rule, you **always** use queues at the outputs of the tee so that it doesn't block your pipelines.
- Another option to avoid blocking is to set `async=false` in your sink elements.
- Try setting `dts-method=2` to the `mp4mux` to see if it makes a difference.
- The first troubleshooting line when working gstreamer is using the debug. Please inspect and share the output of `GST_DEBUG=2 gst-launch-1.0 ...`.